# Microsoft Azure: Can't SSH after restart

Tags: ubuntu, azure, ssh, virtual-machine

I've been running an Ubuntu VM on Azure for the past year or so, today after shutting down the machine and starting it again after 5 minutes I've been unable to SSH into it at all, getting 'Operation Timed Out' errors.

I've been searching for answers for a few hours but nothing seems close to this problem where connectivity can't be done in any way.

Another thing that started after the restart is the Host Name is set to empty

Comment: I think this question would better fit to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you did a shutdown, IP of machine has been changed. Check it in the control panel.